# Using password to unlock Windows Hello PIN lockout

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-hello

I have set up Windows Hello using fingerprint and PIN as a backup on my Windows 10 laptop. Right now I can also log in using my regular password if I want to. From what I've read the PIN is backed by the Trusted Platform Module (TPM) hardware chip (mine has TPM 2.0) and if a PIN is typed incorrectly too many times it will lock down. If this happens to me, can I still use the regular Windows password to unlock it? According to [this Microsoft support article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/manage-tpm-lockout) I can open tpm.msc to reset the PIN if I have the owner's password, is this the same as the Windows user account password? Also, if the computer is locked, how am I able to open tpm.msc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure when you are locked out from your pin, windows will ask you if you want to login using your password instead. In either case, you can switch to login using your password, and once you are logged in, you can reset the pin or remove the lockout. I have done so in the past so I know for sure that you can get in.

The owners password is the windows user account password, yes.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the answer I was hoping for!

Answer (score 0):

IF a) your profile is tied to a MS account, b) you are locked out of your pin and c) have a hardware security key tied to your MS account....then windows Windows will ask you to present that key for login.  At that point you can reset your pin.